# Two redmines connected? Is that possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crm, redmine

How to connect two redmines between each other, if someone have a clue that would be great!

So basically whenever we update first redmine, the second should be updated via email, parsing JSON, etc

So basically I need to solve tasks:

1. Automate task update in both Redmines
2. Make sure that transparency is in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no tool to synchronize between two redmine instances.

However, if you have a 'live' instance of redmine, and a 'read-only' instance, you could simply regularly dump the database of the *live* instance and re-create the database for the *read-only* instance.

Answer (score 2):

If mysql replication (master-slave/master-master) cannot be done (maybe due to connectivity issues or if not the whole db should be replicated), there are still some options, as mentioned in this thread:
http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/29725

The nicest way may be rubyrep, which allows for selective replication (i.e. if you may only want to replicate some projects):
http://www.rubyrep.org/

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you effectively do this with mysql replication to the tables for the other install?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0 of [TaskAdapter project](http://www.taskadapter.com) is aimed to provide synchronization you described. It's not   released yet, though.